# Remove string between special character JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I trying to remove some string from string which I have.

I have following string.

```
"[1fe3-46675-be1a-cd97084b]^Some Text@ dsd dsds [4j34-46675-be1a-cd97854b]^Another Text@"
```

I want to remove text between ^ @ including that character.

Output should be `"[1fe3-46675-be1a-cd97084b] dsd dsds [4j34-46675-be1a-cd97854b]"`

I used following but, not removing that string.

```js
let str = "[1fe3-46675-be1a-cd97084b]^Some Text@ dsd dsds [4j34-46675-be1a-cd97854b]^Another Text@"

str = str.replace(/^.*@/g, '');

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with this regex.

```js
let stringsS = "[1fe3-46675-be1a-cd97084b]^Some Text@ dsd dsds [4j34-46675-be1a-cd97854b]^Another Text@"
let regex = /\^(.*?)\@/gi

console.log(stringsS.replace(regex,''));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
str = "[1fe3-46675-be1a-cd97084b]^Some Text@ dsd dsds [4j34-46675-be1a-cd97854b]^Another Text@";
replacedStr = str.replace(/\^[^@]*\@/g, '');
console.log(replacedStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the `^` as in:

`str = str.replace(/\^.*@/, '')`;

The `^` means something in regex and must be escaped if you want it to be treated as normal character